# How to poll an API safely and efficiently?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an enterprise iOS app in Swift that needs to pull a list of items from our API and display them in a table view.

The list may change a few times a day but our system won't notify us when the data changes.

Instead, the app will need to poll regularly, say every two hours, to get the latest data and refresh the list. I have implemented the API call using NSURLSession directly.

My question is, what is a safe and efficient way to set up a polling mechanism? What if there are additional API services that must be polled, perhaps on different intervals?

Comment: Since you are an enterprise app you can abuse a background mode such as VoIP to periodically check/load the data, but a cleaner approach would be to have an additional task on a server somewhere that checks the data and sends a push notification to your devices

Comment: @Paulw11 - I have used push notifications in the past for this purpose, but the system here is an old vendor system that does not support events.

Comment: I realise the system itself doesn't support events. I was suggesting creating some code on another server to do the polling and send the push notification rather than trying to poll from the devices themselves - which is more difficult to implement and can have a negative impact on battery life and cellular daa usage.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An efficient polling mechanism can be implemented via NSTimer(s).

You can have multiple NSTimers fetching data from different locations and working on different dispatch queues.

Then, when you fetch new data, you can broadcast a local notification with the new objects (which is similar to Core Data model).

Your app would be able to access the retrieved data from anywhere.

If you only need to use the data in one location, you could use a delegate or a block-ish callback model.

Comment: An NSTimer will stop once the app is in the background

Answer (score 3):

Since you are developing an enterprise app and don't need app store approval you can 'misuse' one of the existing background modes, such as VoIP to periodically poll your data.

My suggestion, however, is to implement some code on another server that can poll the API and send a push notification to the devices when there is new data.  This will be simpler to implement in the iOS app and more efficient in terms of battery life and data traffic.  It also won't require the user to restart your app after device resets.

You can also easily use the same server to check additional data sources in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm accepting @Matteo's because it best answers what I need right now.

Comment: That's fine as long as you realise that an NSTimer will stop when your app isn't in the foreground

Comment: Thanks for that. I have experienced that with NSTimer before so I will have to work around it.